# Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<select th:field="*{role}">
    <option value="#" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Role...</option>
    <option th:each="r : ${roles}" th:value="${r}" th:text="${r.name}">Developer</option>
</select>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Field error in object 'collaborator' on field 'role': rejected value
[33]; codes
[typeMismatch.collaborator.role,typeMismatch.role,typeMismatch.com.imprender.instateam.model.Role,typeMismatch];
arguments
[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
codes [collaborator.role,role]; arguments []; default message [role]];
default message [*Failed to convert property value of type
'java.lang.String' to required type
'com.imprender.instateam.model.Role' for property 'role'*; nested
exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of
type 'java.lang.String' to required type
'com.imprender.instateam.model.Role' for property 'role': no matching
editors or conversion strategy found]
```

It says:

```
**Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.imprender.instateam.model.Role' for property
'role'**
```

but I don't understand where I am doing that.

I think I am not properly transmiting the value selected in the . I thought the object sent would be the one declared in the `value`option that gets selected, but obviously I got it wrong and can't find the way to do it properly.

The model:

```
package com.imprender.instateam.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

@Entity
public class Collaborator {

    @Id
    //Todo: check strategy
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\\s*)+")
    private String name;

    //Todo: check, do we want to create a new table to associate values?

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;

    public Collaborator() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Comment: please remove one of the duplicated questions you have created, either this question or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491380/failed-to-convert-property-value-of-type-java-lang-string-to-required-type-c)

Comment: Also, could you provide more info? like the model you're trying to render...

Comment: Done! I thought the other one was not published, thanks :)

Comment: Check [this post](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) it may guide you about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in your select says the field is a role, entity type Role, but in your options the value is an ID, some primitive value, then doesnt match. You can change to this

```
<select th:field="*{role.id}">
    <option value="#" disabled = "disabled" selected="selected">Role...</option>
    <option th:each="r : ${roles}" th:value="${r.id}" th:text="${r.name}">Developer</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Okey... I just made your change and IT WORKS!

But I would like to know...why??

The field of the bound object was a Role, not a String, why can I substitute that by an id instead and it works?

Comment: I mean, the `th:file={*role.id}` is a field of a bound Object of type `Collaborator`

And the filed is a Role, not a Long ( the Role id is a Long), how can this work?

When working with bound object in thymeleaf...we should use the id instead of the total object?

Comment: the id of your options must to be a primitive object or enum, but with an object you could have problems, and not sure if even would work